# How to check if which hook triggered the call to a function?

Tags: hooks, actions, callbacks

I have a situation where I have a function hooked to more than one custom hooks.
How to check in the callback function which custom hook triggered the call?

Or the question in code will be

```
add_action('my_test_hook_1','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_2','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_3','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_4','my_test_callback_function');

function my_test_callback_function(){

    $called_action_hook = ; //Some magic code that will return current called action the hook

    echo "This function is called by action: " . $called_action_hook ;

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to extract the shared code inside `my_test_callback_function` into a separate function. What's the problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the magic code you need.

Use `current_filter()`. This function will return name of the current filter or action.

```
add_action('my_test_hook_1','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_2','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_3','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_4','my_test_callback_function');

function my_test_callback_function(){

    $called_action_hook = current_filter(); // ***The magic code that will return the last called action

    echo "This function is called by action: " . $called_action_hook ;

}
```

For reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_filter/

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be to add a parameter to `do_action` and then pick that up in your `add_action` function:

```
add_action('my_test_hook_1','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_2','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_3','my_test_callback_function');
add_action('my_test_hook_4','my_test_callback_function');

function my_test_callback_function( $called_action_hook ){
    echo "This function is called by action: " . $called_action_hook ;
}

do_action('my_test_hook_1','my_test_hook_1');
do_action('my_test_hook_2','my_test_hook_2');
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sunil Jaiswal,

it's a good idea. But what if the case that we can't edit the do_action().
I can only edit my callback function unfortinatly as I have a lot of do_actions like this around my theme